# Finding 2 vectors orthogonal to each other and a given vector

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, cross-product, vectors

given vector: $u = <1, -7, 2>$
Find a vector $v$ and $w$ which are are orthogonal to each other and to $u$

I tried the following:
$$ v \cdot u = <1,1,c> \cdot <1,-7,2> \rightarrow c= 3$$
$$ v = <1,1,3>$$
$$ Proof: v \cdot u = 0 \rightarrow True$$
For $w$, I used cross multiplication:
$$\begin{array} c<1,-7,2> \\ <1,1,3> \end{array}  $$
$$ w=<-23,-1,8> $$
When I try to prove it it keeps failing:
$$Proof: v \cdot w= 0 \rightarrow True $$
$$Proof: u \cdot w= 0 \rightarrow False \rightarrow -14 $$

I tried looking for my mistake with no luck. I am sure there is a step I am not understanding correctly or I cannot see it after staring at it for such a long time. Can anyone look at this and let me know where I went wrong ?

Comment: $u\cdot w=\langle1,-7,2\rangle\cdot\langle-23,-1,8\rangle=-23+7+16=0$; $v\cdot w=\langle1,1,3\rangle\cdot\langle-23,-1,8\rangle=-23-1+24=0$

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón, Ty totally could not see that -1... Should call it a night ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the final calculation of $u \cdot w$. We have
$$u \cdot w = \langle 1, -7, 2 \rangle \cdot \langle -23, -1, 8 \rangle = 1(-23)+(-7)(-1)+2(8)
=-23+7+16=0.$$

Comment: HAHA, totally forgot that -1, what a clutz! thanks.